# AS3: How can I stop and loop FLV playback?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flvplayback

I'm trying to make a credits page with a video playing in the background and when the menu button on screen is clicked you will be taken to the main menu and the video will stop. When debugging my app though, the following code cause it to cycle through all 5 scenes at lightspeed, not sure what causes this. I'll show you what code it likes and what code it doesn't.

Bugged code:

```
stop();

import fl.video.*;
import flash.events.VideoEvent;

Playback.source = "TONIGHT'S THE NIGHT.flv";

function FLVDone(event:VideoEvent):void{
    event.target.stop();
}

Playback.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, FLVDone);

function FLVDone(event:VideoEvent):void{
    event.target.stop();
}

//Menu Button
btnMenu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, Menu5Clicked);

function Menu5Clicked (e:MouseEvent){
    gotoAndStop(1)
    FLVDone()
}
```

Working Code with no stop feature:

```
stop();

import fl.video.*;
import flash.events.VideoEvent;

Playback.source = "TONIGHT'S THE NIGHT.flv";

//Menu Button
btnMenu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, Menu5Clicked);

function Menu5Clicked (e:MouseEvent){
    gotoAndStop(1)
}
```

Here's the output

> WARNING: Duplicate label, Scene=Scene 1, Layer=BG, Frame=2, Label=Credits
> WARNING: Duplicate label, Scene=Scene 1, Layer=BG, Frame=3, Label=Credits
> WARNING: Duplicate label, Scene=Scene 1, Layer=BG, Frame=4, Label=Credits
> WARNING: Duplicate label, Scene=Scene 1, Layer=BG, Frame=5, Label=Credits
>
> Fonts should be embedded for any text that may be edited
> at runtime, other         than text with the "Use Device Fonts"
> setting. Use the Text > Font Embedding command to embed fonts.

this appears in both versions of the code when debugged

Comment: This is very likely because your code is wrong. It basically ignores all of your code including `stop();` Check the output panel to see what errors occur. Also, please post `FLVDone`.

Comment: forgot i left out that function, sorry about that. So far it listens to the code works until I add an event listener to the FLV Player (Playback).

Comment: /having the FLVDone function exist it likes, having the event listener exist, it freaks out.

Comment: on your `Menu5Clicked` method, you call `FLVDone()` without any arguments.  You need to either change it to `FLVDone(null)`, or change the method signature to `function FLVDone(event:VideoEvent = null):void`  - you're also missing some semicolons.  As @null says, please post the error from the output panel

Comment: @LDMS he cannot, it uses the parameter. I'm glad you pointed out where the function is, I didn't see it.

Comment: output listed, even with function FLVDone(null) and/or function FLVDone(event:VideoEvent = null):void, the same error i've been having happens

Comment: When you do that though (as @null points out), you should get a "cannot access a method of a null object" error on the line `event.target.stop()` .   Maybe post your .fla if you can, that would be easiest.

Comment: @RyanStLouis thank you for adding that. Please add add my name with an @ as I did with yours in this comment. That way I get a notification and see that something happened here. Why do you have 3 identical frame labels? Please give them unique names.